# Issues with Objects in a linkedlist

Tags: java, object

On my count method, i am trying to compare the object being sent with the object calling it, and I have no idea why i can not cal o.get(i) to get the value for Object o being passed. It tells me the method cannot be found even though i can call get(i) normally. Any ideas how i can get the value for the object getting passed so i can compare them?

```
public class GenericLinkedList<E> implements List<E> {

private class Node<E>{
    private E data;
    private Node<E> next;
}
private E data;
private Node<E> head = null;
private int size = 0;

private Node<E> nodeAt(int index){
    Node<E> curNode = head;
    int curIndex = 0;
    while(curIndex < index){
        curNode = curNode.next;
        curIndex++;
    }
    return curNode;
}

@Override
public E get(int index) {
    return nodeAt(index).data;
}

@Override
public void add(E value) {
    Node<E> node = new Node<E>();
    node.data = value;

    if(size == 0){
        head = node;
    }else{
        Node<E> curNode = nodeAt(size - 1);
        curNode.next = node;
    }
    size++;
}

public void add(int index, E value){
    Node<E> node = new Node<E>();
    node.data = value;

    if(size == 0){
        head = node;
    }else if(index == 0){
        node.next = head;
        head = node;
    }else{
        Node<E> curNode = nodeAt(index - 1);
        node.next = curNode.next;
        curNode.next = node;
    }
    size++;
}

@Override
public void remove(int index) {
    if(index == 0){
        head = head.next;
    }else{
        Node<E> curNode = nodeAt(index - 1);
        curNode.next = curNode.next.next;
    }
    size--;

}

@Override
public void set(int index, E value) {
    nodeAt(index).data = value;

}

public String toString(){
    String s = "";
    Node<E> curNode = head;
    s += curNode.data +" -> ";
    while(curNode.next != null){
        curNode = curNode.next;
        s += curNode.data +" -> ";
    }
    s += "null";
    return s;
}

public void clear() {     

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        set(i, null);

    size = 0;
}

@Override 
public void removeAll(E o)//Clears out the array object by setting everything to null
{        
    for(int i = 0; i < this.size; i++)
    {    

    }
}

@Override
public int count(Object o)
{
    System.out.println(o);
    int count = 0; 

    for(int i = 0; i< size;i++)
    {
        if(get(i) == o.get(i))
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;


    /*int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i<this.size;i++)
    {
    for(int j = 0;i<size;j++)
    {

    }
    }
    return count;*/

}

public void reverse()
{
    int x = size;
    for(int i = 0; i < this.size; i++)
    {
        E temp = this.get(x);
        this.set(x, get(i));
        this.set(i, temp);
        x++;        

    }

}

public Object subList(int beginIndex, int endIndex)
{
    int j = 0;
    GenericLinkedList<E> LinkedList = new GenericLinkedList<E>();
    if(beginIndex == endIndex)
        return LinkedList;
    else if(beginIndex > endIndex||endIndex>size||beginIndex<0)
    {
        return null;
    }
    else 
    {
        for(int i = beginIndex; i <= endIndex;i++)
        {              
            LinkedList.add(get(i));
            j++;
        }
    }        

    return LinkedList;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    GenericLinkedList<Integer> myList = new GenericLinkedList<Integer>();
    myList.add(4);
    myList.add(7);
    myList.add(123123);

    System.out.println(myList.get(2));

    GenericLinkedList<Integer> myList2 = new GenericLinkedList<Integer>();
    myList2.add(4);
    myList2.add(7);
    myList2.add(8);
    myList2.add(3,999);
    System.out.println(myList2);       

    System.out.println(myList.count(myList2));

    //System.out.println(myList2);
    // myList2.clear();//Testing our clear class     
    // System.out.println(myList2);  
    //System.out.println(myList2.subList(1, 3));//Testing our clear class     
    // System.out.println(myList2);  

}
```

}

Comment: You're calling `get` on the `Object` reference, you may want to cast `o` to `GenericLinkedList` before calling `o.get(i)` or you can change the `count(Object o)` method to take in a `GenericLinkedList` parameter.

Comment: Thats how I had it before and i was getting the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem when trying to call `o.get()` because it is an object of the base type Object which has no method get defined.  To get the proper result you have two possible solutions....

The short solution is to type cast.

```
   ((GenericLinkedList<Object>)o).get(i)
```

Or a more easily readable solution is to change the signature of your count method:

```
public int count(GenericLinkList<E> list) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: This worked out, but when calling it from my main method, how would i cast myList?

Comment: If both are the same type of list (i.e. GenericLinkList<Integer>) just call list.count(list2);  If they are different objects you can still do comparisons just it may be a bit more complicated, requiring some casting and a few assumptions most likely

Answer (score 0):

Change your count method to `public int GenericLinkedList(Object o)`

If you use Object as the type of the parameter, you can only call the methods which are available on Object.